# Convert '01-Feb-15' to Python date 01/02/2015

Tags: python, python-datetime

tbk = '01-Feb-15'

I wish to convert to datetime so that tbk = 01/02/2015 I have tried the following:-

```
  tbk = datetime.datetime.strptime(tbk, '%d-%b-%y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

I receive the following error:- ValueError: time data '01-Feb-15' does not match format '%d-%b-%Y'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: nothing, but it doesn't look like you're using the actual code you've posted here because your example produces the correct result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your error message you have capital Y which implies that you try to use format '%d-%b-%Y' instead of '%d-%b-%y' that you wrote on the example. For me, the example worked just fine.

Comment: Sorry  posted wrong error:raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '01/02/2015' does not match format '%d-%b-%y'

Comment: That is because you have `/` in your data but `-` in your format specification. Processing dates takes a *lot* of attention to minor details.